# get_option() does unserialize and don't remove \

Tags: database, options

When i `update_option()` with special caracter, for exemple **BARCA D'AREGOS** the serialize option puts save like that BARCA D\'AREGOS on database. If i do `get_option()` the display value is **BARCA D\'AREGOS**.

`stripslashes()` don't work. Anyone have solution?

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/319318/edit) to include the `update_option()` code. In some quick testing, `serialize()` doesn't seem to add `\` characters to the serialized data, so something else is going on here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The get_option function is necessary for you using maybe_unserialize. 
update_option() function maybe_serialize passed.

```
// store data time use maybe_unserialize.
$data = maybe_serialize( $data );

// get/display time user maybe_unserialize
$data = maybe_unserialize( $data );
```

Please check it with above example code

Comment: WordPress handles serialization & unserialization for you when you use the `*_option()` functions. From the [`get_option()` docs](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_option/): "If the option was serialized then it will be unserialized when it is returned."